# Powershell Monitoring Script as Background task

Tags: .net, powershell

I am developing a monitoring application using power-shell which gets process ID and app pool name from within a windows server and sorts the process which takes the highest CPU in real time. This application is helpful during my tests however i have to run the power-shell script every time to achieve this. How do i run the script in the background just a like a service which executes second ?.
This script runs on a performance test machine so i would like to background execution to be really silent and shouldn't impact server performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [scheduled tasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649810.aspx) and [scheduled jobs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/18/create-a-powershell-scheduled-job.aspx) (Windows Server 2012 onwards / Windows 8 onwards).

Answer (score 0):

If you use PowerGUI Script editor(free from http://www.quest.com/powergui-freeware/) you can go to *Tools-> Compile Script into Service* which will do all the hard work for you.

Once you get the compiled executable you can transfer it to any other machine along with exported registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\YourPowershellServiceName`. This is useful if you don't want to install PowerGUI on a production box.